# How to know if a file is checked out by someone else in TFS 2010?

Tags: vcs-checkout

I want to make sure no one else is checking out the source codes so that I can make a released installer. So, I want to see 1) the `#1` list of users who are checking out a specific file and 2) the `#2` list of all checked out files ; but I don't know how to. Please help if you do!

**Edit**

A colleague show me that we can see the list `#1` on per user basic by: `Source Control - Team Members - Right click a user - Show Pending Changes - Done`. This is great but not perfect. Would be lovely to see the whole list of every member.

One more step to follow to see the whole list `Modify Query` (on the left top corner) and select `Display all checked out`.

Comment: try checking out exclusive; if you can't then someone else has it checked out. Look in output window to see who has it

Comment: @Mitch: A project may contain hundreds of files. Is there another way to see the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A colleague show me that we can see the list `#1` on per user basic by: `Source Control - Team Members - Right click a user - Show Pending Changes - Done`. This is great but not perfect. Would be lovely to see the whole list of every member.

One more step to follow to see the whole list `Modify Query` (on the left top corner) and select `Display all checked out`.

Comment: In Source Control Explorer I can see files and who checked out some of them. But I don't see Team Members in Team Explorer. Or where I should see them? And where is Modify Query? I can't find it.

Comment: Btw, in Solution Explorer I see icon of human instead of lock before name of file and tooltip: 'Checkout by someone else or in another place'. It would be much better if I could get name of person, who checked out this file in tooltip.

Answer (score 19):

Open a Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt (Start->All Programs->MS Visual Studio 2010->VS Tools).
Type:

```
tf status /user:*
```

This will give you all pending changes for all users in all workspaces.

For a specific file, just type:

```
tf status /user:* c:\myfile.txt
```

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s5ae285.aspx).

Comment: How can I get the result printed into a file?

Comment: Redirect the output.  Example: tf status /user:* > c:\test.txt

Comment: +1 Works great, pity though, that TFS doesn't tell you *when* a file was checked out, that sort of thing can matter for larger projects.

Comment: @ChrisO: It will tell you when if you ask for detailed output: `/format:detailed`.

Comment: @KurtHutchinson - perhap I should RTM ;-) that I might actually learn something.  At any rate can you post this great info along with a nice sample command as an answer?

Comment: FYI, you can add this as an External tool on VS: *Tools -> External Tools* - add new tool with the following details : Title: *Whatever you want* Command: *%VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\IDE\tf.exe* Arguments: *status $(ItemPath) /user:* /recursive* Initial Directory: *$(ItemDir)*. Enjoy. (p.s. if you have VS2012, use **VS110COMNTOOLS**) [sample in VS2010](http://i.imgur.com/dO5sL4B.png)

Answer (score 3):

I think Team Foundation Sidekicks (http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) is much easier then using the command prompt.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's "easier" to pay instead using the command line. please see my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273569/how-to-know-if-a-file-is-checked-out-by-someone-else-in-tfs-2010/4273685#comment26769340_4273685)

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, look in the Source Control Explorer (View menu > Other Windows > Source Control Explorer).  That will show you who has each file checked out and if they have an exclusive lock on the file.

Comment: @Lam: With your suggestion, I guess it is not easy to see a checked-out file which lies under tens of folder - the project would contains tens of folders/subfodlers with hundreds of files for each folder

Answer (score 1):

> `#1 Solution`

1. Open `Source Control Explorer`.
2. In this explorer browse to the file and select it.
3. `File > Source Control > Find in Source Control > Status...`
4. Don't change anything in this opened window and click `Find`

> `#2 Solution`

1. `View > Other Windows > Pending Changes`

Answer (score 0):

Goto `Views-->Other windows -->pending changes`

Comment: But I see only my check-out there.